# Saving activity state on screen Orientation change

Tags: android, datepicker

A DatePicker dialog is opened and it displays the default date.I then select a desired date and then rotate the screen. I observe that the selected date is replaced by default date. Is there a way to retain the selected date after screen rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using another layout for the landscape mode (by using the qualifier) then try adding this to your manifest.xml

```
<activity name= ".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: I am getting the desired behavior. Thanks a lot. I wonder whether it is a good practice to put android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" always in Androidmanifest ?

Comment: no, its not. This solution worked because you are not using a different layout for landscape mode. Because both layouts are same, this solution works. 
Use this only if you have one layout definition

Answer (score 0):

You can place the DatePicker in a `DialogFragment`, which manages the lifecycle for you: [Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Comment: I am already doing it.but the date-picker was discarding my selected custom date and showed default date.Adding "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"" to AndroidManisfest works well. Thanks.